# What is the probability of 5 specific players all being put into the same group with 9 groups of 5 players?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm trying to calculate the probability of all 5 specific players making it into the same group when there are 9 groups of 5 players each.

How would I go about calculating this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: calculate the probability of all 5 players selected into group #1 then multiply it by 9.

Comment: @BrianTHannan There are $C_5^{45}$ ways to pick a group of $5$ players out of $45$ and one way to put $5$ specific players in that group.

Comment: That's much clearer. I like that. So C(45,5) = 1221759 and since there is just one way to put 5 players in the same group it would be 1/1221759?

Comment: @BrianTHannan: You've got it

Comment: I appreciate it! You are the man. It's been a long while since I've actually calculated probabilities. I usually just estimate in my head. I knew this one was very close to zero percent chance but I wanted to make sure I knew how to do the actual math.

Comment: Actually, is it going to be (1/1221759) * 9 or just 1/1221759?

Comment: It's going to be $\frac{9}{1221759}$